# Rails model for recipes and sub-recipes association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

How would i make one table of items with the following associations:

My end goal is to be able to create recipes that have many components and sub-recipes (which I want to combine into one drop down)

```
Component

  belongs_to sub_recipe

End

Sub_recipe

  has_many components

  belongs_to recipe

End

Recipe 

  has_many subrecipes

  has_many components

End
```

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a single table for each item, and a table for associations

```
#class RawComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
#  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
#end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_components
  has_many :subrecipes, :through => :recipe_components
  has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_components
#  has_and_belongs_to_many :raw_components
end

class RecipeComponents < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :subrecipe, :class_name => :Recipe
end
```

Supposing you had a @recipe, you could then go:

```
@recipe.subrecipes # find all subrecipes required to make this recipe
@recipe.recipes # find all recipes using this as a subrecipe
```

Also added possible RawComponent class, which you can use for things not made up of other components. But you don't need it, if you make every RawComponent a Recipe without any subrecipes, which is also a valid way of modeling the situation.

The key takeaway is that the association model (RecipeComponents) belongs to a :recipe which is higher in the hierarchy, and a :subrecipe, which is lower in the hierarchy, but of the same class type as recipe.

Comment: Brilliant. You're the best ronalchn!

Comment: ronalchn, when you say "You want a single table for each item" do you mean I _only_ need a recipe table? If so, what columns do I need to add to it to represent these associations correctly?

Comment: I mean you need two tables. One for storing the items, and one for storing the associations.